# Google Tag Manager Virtual Page View

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a little problem setting up a virtualPageView which should override the URL which is sent to google when no result is present.

Heres what I have as JavaScript code:

```
function returnNoSearchResultsGoogleTagManagerCode($searchterm){
    if ($searchterm == "") return "";

    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&no_result=".$searchterm;


    $js = "<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             dataLayer.push({
                 'event':'empty_result',
                 'virtualPageURL':'".$requestUri."'
                });
            });


    </script>";

    return $js;
}
```

As you can see, I want to use an event trigger (empty_result).

In google, I use a Trigger to determine if the Page is a no result Page. First i created a custom Variable with custom JS

```
    function(){
       if (document.getElementsByClassName('ga-no-result').length > 0){
            return true;
       }else{
            return false
       }
   }
```

The class is set, if the SearchEngine can't find a result. So far so good.
I also created a dataLayer variable to hold the virtualPageURL

[image: dataLayer]

Now I need an event which is triggered if the variable is true.

[image: Event SearchEmptyResult]

Finally I created a Tag with type PageView which is fired when the event occurs:

[image: Google Tag]

Until now it seems okay, the Tag is properly configured (i guess) but if I do a search which has no result, the Page URL **is not overridden**

[image]

The Tag is properly fired and the variables are filled. The overview of the dataLayer shows a correct dataLayer event.
But the PageURL is not overridden... Even if I wait a whole day, the category isn't sent to google.

What am I doing wrong?
I would be very thankful if someone would have an idea or even a solution :)

Thanks in advance

exa.byte

UPDATE:

Hey, I forgot to mention, that I want to use the new page variable as the string which google should use to determine the searchterm and the searchcategory
In Google Analytics I configuered the search as the "q" parameter and the "no_result" as the category.
Is it even possible to change the string which google will parse in the end?

Comment: I think for virtual page view you have to change Field "page" - in your GTM-OnSearchEmptyResult you are changing "{{Page URL}}"  - I don't think that's correct way to send virutal pageview. Also if you need to change hostname use Fieldname "hostname".

Comment: What Matus said (should be an answer IMO). Also both having a custom event for empty result pages _and_ testing for empty results in a custom var seems redundant.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your answers. The variable "page" does not exist... as you can see on the screenshot, I have access to "Page URL", Page Path" and "Page Hostname"

@EikePierstorff 
I dont't get your comment completely. I use the Boolean-Var to test if the page is an empty_result. I can't see redundancy here. Could you please explain?

The bool is just used to have a trigger, and the virtualPageView is the dataLayer which I need as I configured in the Tag, that values from the DataLayer can override the built in vars.
Maybe I'm getting it wrong :(

Comment: In the "set fields" interface the leftmost textbox is not for a variable, it is for the field whose value you want to change. The data field that hold the current page path is called "page". So if you want to overwrite the current page path with the virtual Url you do it by setting the "page" field to the value of your virtual page path variable. For a better understanding how this works look at the field reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Comment: @EikePierstorff All right, thank you. I set it up as you suggested, but still no luck

the "fieldname" is now "page" (without ") and the value is still "{{virtualPageURL}}" (without ")

But when i review with the GTM-Preview tool the Page URL is still the one which is in the browser-addressbar :(

Comment: Don't forget to refresh your page after making changes.. I know it sounds stupid but it actually happens a lot :p

Comment: No problem, was that the problem? :p

Answer (score 2):

To send a virtual pageview to Google Analytics, the field you need to change is **page** not **{{Page Url}}** , also the **title** field is often used.

That's really the only two things you need to do to send a simple virtual pageview.

Extra: I always start my pagepath with **/virtual/** to be able to recognize which ones are virtual pageviews easily in GA

Answer (score 1):

For virtual page view you have to change Field "page" - in your GTM-OnSearchEmptyResult you are changing "{{Page URL}}" - I don't think that's correct way to send virutal pageview. Also if you need to change hostname use Fieldname "hostname".

In preview mode you will not see Page URL changed in Variables Tab, you have to go to the actual GA tag that is fired and check it's values. You can either do this in GTM's preview tool or you can use standard developer tools - Network Tab and see what values are being sent to GA:

[image]

You can see "dl" parameter is the current page, if you set up virtual page you should also see parameter called "dp" this is going to be the new value of page in your GA.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I can see a "dp" variable in my networktab.
@Matus Does googl now uses this variable to check for searchterms and search categorys? (thats the thing I actually want to do with the url string)

I will update the questen, thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup virtual pageview you have to use **page** instead of {{Page URL}} in your **fieldname** and for **Document title** use **title** in you fieldname.
for more **field reference** of google analytics follow below link 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitType.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around with custom Tag Manager events it's still possible to use the good old `ga` method, even if you don't include the Analytics code on the page. You just need to fetch the right tracker dynamically, as explained by [Simo Ahava in this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/EdC7TVyaCMw).

```
if (typeof ga === "function") {
  ga.getAll().forEach((tracker) => {
    tracker.set('page', '/my/path'); // <- change here
    tracker.send('pageview');
  });  
}
```

I also put it in a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/hannesl/97af3132cc0d1efc72e86e872438f5b4).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I think I got rid of the Problem and have solved it now. I will describe my solution below:

The solution is quite simple.

1. I had an error/ spelling error @ google backend. I set the search_category parameter to "no_results", but used "no_result" for implementation...
   Pretty dumb, but sometimes you just won't see the wood for the trees...
2. I created a new Trigger as helper "HelperDomReady" to trigger the only if DOM is ready and the variable "isEmptySearch" equals "(bool)true"

Now I can see the searchterms which have no result in google backend in the "sitesearch categories" summary. Since I won't set the parameter at all, if the search had at least one hit, the site-search category shows "not-set" for successful results. Therfore the category-section will only show searches without a hit. Problem solved :)

Disadvantage: The searchterm is also listed in the normal list. But I think this is negligible